# Not able to use angular CLI in asp.net core SPA project in VS Code - Get error ng is not recognized as the name of cmdlet

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, .net-core, visual-studio-code, angular-cli

In the beginning when I created project based on aspnetcore-spa in VS code I was able to use Angular. At some point during project development I came across scenario where RXJS 6.0.0 was needed. I looked in my package.JSON and I had RXJS 5.5.6. So i decided to do npm install on RXJS latest which further broke my existing components saying they are dependent on older version of RXJS. In doing this install and uninstall in VS Code CLI for some reason I also broke my Angular CLI. I dont want to install latest Angular CLI because my project is on Older Angular version and I am not sure how do I check it. Could someone shed some light on how do I get back my Angular CLI for version that works in my aspnetcore-spa project in VS Code ?

When I try to run any Angular cli command inside my project folder in VS code I get following error :

ng g component Test
ng : The term 'ng' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, 
or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ ng g component Test
+ ~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (ng:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Below is my Package.json

```
{
  "name": "vega",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --extract-css",
    "build": "ng build --extract-css",
    "build:ssr": "npm run build -- --app=ssr --output-hashing=media",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.2.5",
    "@angular/cdk": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/material": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.2.0",
    "@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader": "^5.0.0-beta.5",
    "@sentry/browser": "^5.6.1",
    "ajv": "^6.0.0",
    "aspnet-prerendering": "^3.0.1",
    "auth0-js": "^9.11.3",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "ngx-toastr": "^8.10.2",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.6",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.5.3",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.19"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "~1.7.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.2.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.3",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "^4.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~4.1.0",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "~2.5.3"
  },
  "optionalDependencies": {
    "node-sass": "^4.9.0"
  }
}
```

Running ng --version in node.js shows me following. Should I revert my Angular version globally to 5.2.0 and install CLI version to 1.7.0 ?

[image]

Comment: You are using Powershell? did you try using cmd? check your ide config.
Can you build an angular project outside?
Also when updating Rxjs, use ng update, because of the other dependencies.

Comment: I am not using powershell. I am using terminal inside Visual Studio Code. It is not stand alone angular project but as part of asp.net core spa project template. What do I check my IDE Config for ?

Comment: Its probably using PowerShell if you are in windows, can you try the commands from a clean cmd

Answer (score 0):

> At first you have to set up in your environment
> variable of your system. If you are using windows then go to your
> environment variable to set it up.

## If You Don't  Then Follow Following Steps:

- From the desktop, right click the **My Computer** or **This PC** or **computer** icon.
- Select **Properties** from the context menu.
- Select the **Advanced system settings** link.
- Click on **Environment Variables**. If the **PATH** environment variable does not exist, click **New** and *create* one
- In the **Edit Environment Variable** window, put the value of the **PATH** environment variable. Which should be. According to my machine it should be like bellow **C:\users[My_USER_Name]\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@angular\cli\bin**
- Click **OK**. Close all remaining windows by clicking `OK`.
- Reopen Command prompt window, and run `ng new MyApp`. It should work now.